# JSON is printed with backslashes

Tags: mysql, json, hibernate, spring-boot, jackson

```
{"externalQueryDate":"4018-11-23"}
```

this is my json string, which is in a column of `mysql`.

I get it with `creditRisk.getCreditRiskDataCodeBased()`

and in `javascript` or in `swagger`, i see with backslashes:

```
"{\"externalQueryDate\":\"4018-11-23\"}"
```

I can use `JSON.parse` in frontend but , i want to solve this is backend.

even

for

```
   StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        objectMapper.writer().writeValue(sw, creditRisk.getCreditRiskDataTermBased());
```

it writes this:

```
"responseCode": "\"{\\\"externalQueryDate\\\":\\\"4018-11-23\\\"}\""
```

I tried those

```
objectMapper.readTree(creditRisk.getCreditRiskDataCodeBased()).toString()
```

and

```
objectMapper.writer().writeValue(sw, creditRisk.getCreditRiskDataTermBased());
```

and

```
@JsonRawValue
    @JsonValue
```

How can i solve this?

In `mysql`, it is also without `slash`es

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse the json string with jackson objectMapper you need to use 'read' and tell it what class to use to create the parsed object from.

So in your case you could do something like

```
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = "{\"externalQueryDate\":\"4018-11-23\"}";

        Map map = objectMapper.readValue(json, Map.class);

        System.out.print(map.get("externalQueryDate"));
```

I've just used a Map here as I don't know what class you're wanting to parse the json into. If you have a class with an externalQueryDate field you can read into that. You could also use @JsonFormat on the field to tell it what the date format is if you want to parse the value straight into a LocalDate field.

I suggest you write a few simple unit tests to get the hang of escaped quotes in strings. It looks like they're causing you some confusion.

Comment: I did not want to use a class to parse with :(

Comment: So what kind of object do you want to parse the JSON into?